# JAVA path.getName(0) returning the entire path instead of first element on a Mac, with windows path

Tags: java, windows, path

I suspect this is a noob mistake on my behalf.  With Java 13 and the following method:

```
    public static void winPath (){
        Path winPath = Paths.get("C:\\the\\wizards\\despicable\\cat");
        System.out.println(String.format("First element of %s is: %s", winPath.toString(), winPath.getName(0)));
    }
```

Calling this method, I would expect to get:

```
First element of C:\the\wizards\despicable\cat is: the
```

Instead I get the entire path:

```
First element of C:\the\wizards\despicable\cat is: C:\the\wizards\despicable\cat
```

This is unexpected behaviour to me, because if I try the same with a macos path:

```
 public static void macPath (){
        Path macpath = Paths.get("/Volumes/Multimedia/the/wizards/despicable/cat");
        System.out.println(String.format("First element of %s is: %s", macpath.toString(), macpath.getName(0)));
    }
```

... the output is as I hoped for:

```
First element of /Volumes/Multimedia/the/wizards/despicable/cat is: Volumes
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Which version of  jdk are you using  now? I can't reproduce in Java 11

Comment: Thanks - I'll add this info to the question. It is Java 13

Comment: Not reproducable on Java 14 either.

Answer (score 1):

`Path` will not divide your string into different elements when you execute this on a non Windows system because it doesn't recognise the file separator, so to create a path where each disk/folder/file is different element you need to create it like this

```
Path winPath = Paths.get("C:", "\\the", "\\wizards", "\\despicable", "\\cat");
```

or even better since you don't want the \ included

```
Path winPath = Paths.get("C:", "the", "wizards", "despicable", "cat");
```

Then you can iterate over your elements

```
winPath.forEach( p ->
    System.out.println(p)
);
```

This is why your second example works as expected when run on a Mac (or a Linux/Unix) machine

```
Paths.get("/Volumes/Multimedia/the/wizards/despicable/cat");
```

will split the given path into different elements, "Volume", "Multimedia" and so on

Comment: That would make perfect sense, except that if I use a macos unix style path such as: 

/Volumes/Multimedia/the/wizards/despicable/cat

The same method returns:

Volumes

I'll update my question to include this...

Comment: I have explained what the issue is with (the first version) of your question so I don't really understand this comment.

Comment: I'm just confused as to why the Path class would tokenise the path when fed a singles string describing the entire Macos path, but when fed a single string describing a windows path, it does not tokenise it.  Inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, I just realised this was the issue. The problem is what the native [filesystem separator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator) is. On a Mac java recognises the "/" as a separator so it can split the path properly but it doesn't recognise "\" so it treats the whole string as a path item.

Comment: Great, thank you: that helps.  Any suggestions as to how one would handle my situation where regardless of the running OS, the code needs to handle paths of various flavours? I'm manipulating an xml file that describes a project file from an app that records paths to resources from any of the OSs that the app can run on. To complicate things further, it records in the xml a history of paths for each resource which, if the user changes OS's and relinked the resources, will contain paths from different OSs...

Comment: But a path on a Mac will never be C:\\the\..., the Path class is meant to handle paths correctly on the OS (filesystem) it is executed on. So it doesn't really know about Windows or MacOS or Linux.

Comment: Do you know of a class designed to help people manipulate paths abstractly from the OS they are running on, with the ability to recognise paths from the main operating systems?  While less common than dealing with local paths, it isn't so rare for an application to need to manipulate paths that will be used on another OS.

Comment: Hello @JoakimDanielson! Could you give me a hand on my new post regarding saving data?